# Switching a button for a menu in Mapbox GL-JS (Show/Hide Layers)

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

Pretty new to this, I'm having trouble with Mapbox trying to switch a button that shows and hides layers using multiple buttons (one per layer), to a single button that drop downs to show each layer. The example found in this link is the base of what I'm trying for, but rather have it in one button than filling space with numerous. Below is the code which allows the button to switch it on and off.

```js
map.on('style.load', function() {
  map.addSource('museums', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr'
  });
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'museums',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'museums',
    'paint': {
      'circle-radius': 8,
      'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
    },
    'source-layer': 'museum-cusco'
  });

  map.addSource('contours', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
  });
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'contours',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'contours',
    'source-layer': 'contour',
    'layout': {
      'line-join': 'round',
      'line-cap': 'round'
    },
    'paint': {
      'line-color': '#877b59',
      'line-width': 1
    }
  });
});

addLayer('Contours', 'contours');
addLayer('Museums', 'museums');

function addLayer(name, id) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '#';
  link.className = 'active';
  link.textContent = name;

  link.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(id, 'visibility');

    if (visibility === 'visible') {
      map.setLayoutProperty(id, 'visibility', 'none');
      this.className = '';
    } else {
      this.className = 'active';
      map.setLayoutProperty(id, 'visibility', 'visible');
    }
  };

  var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
  layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

```html
<nav id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <nav class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">value</a>
  </nav>
```

Previously it used `<nav id="menu"></nav>` for the button but I've added a simple dropdown button as seen below, however I can't for the life of me figure out how to link the two together to substitute the menu button for a dropdown with multiple options. I've tried fiddling with different parts for a while but truth be told I'm lost. Any help for this novice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks